# spark.sql.cbo.enabled=true with Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark 2.2 the Cost Based Optimizer option has been enabled. The documentation appears to be saying that we need to analyze the tables in Spark before enabling this option. I would like to know if this option is helpful when we have all the table data coming in from Hive as the Data storage layer. Since spark will read Hive using Hivetablescan (avoiding Map/Reduce) does it make sense to use CBO configuration when data is read from Hive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1 Liner:

Yes CBO (spark.sql.cbo.enabled=true) is useful with Hive tables also.

#### Explanation:

A HiveTable in Spark is represented by *HiveTableRelation* class. A Spark table (or a DataSource table) is represented by *LogicalRelation* class. Both of these classes extends LeadNode. Spark abstracts out the stats of all sorts of LogicalPlan using the "computeStats" method. Every class can gives its implementation for computeStats.

If the code we can see that HiveTableRelation class has overridden this method to return table and column level stats if they are available. Same thing is done by *LogicalRelation* class.

In HiveTableRelation:

```
  override def computeStats(conf: SQLConf): Statistics = {
    tableMeta.stats.map(_.toPlanStats(output)).getOrElse {
      throw new IllegalStateException("table stats must be specified.")
    }
  }
```

This in turn calls tableMeta.stats.map(_.toPlanStats(output)).

Code in CatalogStatistics:

```
  def toPlanStats(planOutput: Seq[Attribute]): Statistics = {
    val matched = planOutput.flatMap(a => colStats.get(a.name).map(a -> _))
    Statistics(sizeInBytes = sizeInBytes, rowCount = rowCount,
      attributeStats = AttributeMap(matched))
  }
```

This shows that Spark HiveTableRelation has also overridden *computeStats* method and this method returns all the table level as well as column level stats. So if a table has stats generated, they will be used by CBO to optimize the plan.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 

I am running spark.sql ("sql query") to get data into SparkSession using Metastore of Hive.  Eg.
val dbDf4 = spark.sql("select * from dim_customer"); //dim_customer is a table in Hive
dbDf4.createOrReplaceTempView("dim_customer"); //Create a equivalent view to be used in Spark session.

After creating the view, the next set of Spark.sql statements use DIM_CUSTOMER. So, is the CBO still applicable as I am not creating a Spark Table. Also, will it be meaningful to use spark.sql.cbo.enabled=true parameter here?

Comment: @BDA 
say you have val dbDf4 = spark.sql("select * from dim_customer where id > 10"); dbDf4.createOrReplaceTempView("NEW_DIM_CUSTOMER"); 

Here createOrReplaceTempView("NEW_DIM_CUSTOMER") is just a way to register a DataFrame as a view - so that it can be used in sql queries using 'NEW_DIM_CUSTOMER'.

Comment: @BDA contd...

Say if you run spark.sql("select * from NEW_DIM_CUSTOMER join SOME_OTHER_TABLE on NEW_DIM_CUSTOMER.id = SOME_OTHER_TABLE.id"), 
this is equivalent of  spark.sql("select * from (select * from dim_customer where id > 10) x join SOME_OTHER_TABLE on x.id = SOME_OTHER_TABLE.id"),

, CBO is still applicable here. Many of the optimizer rules (like ReorderJoin/JoinSelection) etc can optimize plan. So using spark.sql.cbo.enabled=true is meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

`spark.sql.cbo.enabled=true` is **NOT** useful for Hive tables unless
`ANALYZE TABLE <tblname> COMPUTE STATISTICS NOSCAN`(Basic stats for table, use `FOR COLUMN` for column level statistics)     is fired from Spark.

Spark cannot make of stats collected from running the `ANALYZE` command from Hive.
It can make use of stats only when computed from Spark engine.

### How are stats stored in Hive table

The stats are store in Hive table in `TBLPROPERTIES`.
All the Spark stats have keys with prefix `spark.sql.statistics`.
[Code reference](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveExternalCatalog.scala#L1322).